# python3: matplotlib plotting four lines with dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

Hi there is a dictionary, m={'A':[1.5,3.6,5.7,6,7,8], 'B':[3.5,5,6,8,4,5], 'C':[2.8,3.5,4.5,5.6,7.0,9.0]}. I want to plot three lines with python matplotlib at one figure(like the following figure). The x-aix is the same:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. and three y values is the key(A, B, C)'s values. and A, B, C is three lines labels. how to plot it. I have tried by the following code, but it is wrong, could you tell me how to do it.

[image: sample for what I want]

```
  for k, v in dict_s:
        plt(range(1, 4), v, '.-', label=k)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating a dictionary yields keys only.

```
>>> dict_s = {
...     'A': [1.5, 3.6, 5.7, 6, 7, 8],
...     'B': [3.5, 5, 6, 8, 4, 5],
...     'C': [2.8, 3.5, 4.5, 5.6, 7.0, 9.0]
... }
>>> for x in dict_s:
...     print(x)
...
A
C
B
```

If you need to iterate (key, value) pairs, use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
>>> for x in dict_s.items():
...     print(x)
...
('A', [1.5, 3.6, 5.7, 6, 7, 8])
('C', [2.8, 3.5, 4.5, 5.6, 7.0, 9.0])
('B', [3.5, 5, 6, 8, 4, 5])
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dict_s = {
    'A': [1.5, 3.6, 5.7, 6, 7, 8],
    'B': [3.5, 5, 6, 8, 4, 5],
    'C': [2.8, 3.5, 4.5, 5.6, 7.0, 9.0]
}

for k, v in dict_s.items():
    plt.plot(range(1, len(v) + 1), v, '.-', label=k)
    # NOTE: changed `range(1, 4)` to mach actual values count
plt.legend()  # To draw legend
plt.show()
```

[image: output figure]

Comment: thanks for  @falsetru your kind answer, it is helpful. But I want to plot the labels for each line, how to do it, thanks!

Comment: thanks for @falsetru . I accept it. You are kind guy.